# Суммирование одинаковых строк в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Есть таблица Excel с отчетом по продажам:

[image: пример]

Необходимо просуммировать в python те строки, у которых совпадают значения в колонках A и C ('Артикул склад1' и 'Размер'), к примеру 3 и 4 строка. Нужно удалить дубликаты, а в оставшейся строке суммировать значения в столбцах от E до I. Библиотеку использую Pandas. В приведенном примере, получается, вместо 23 строк должно остаться 17.

У меня пока получилось только сделать проверку на одинаковые строки, но не знаю как суммировать значения в этих строках и удалить лишние:

```
import pandas as pd

#загрузка исходного файла
xls0 = 'C:/Users/1/Desktop/xls1.xlsx'
file = pd.read_excel(xls0)

#определение количества рабочих строк в исходном файле
lines_number = len(file.index)

#создание нового файла
file_new = file.copy()

#удаление всех строк в новом файле
for i in range(lines_number):
    file_new.drop(labels=[i], axis=0, inplace=True)

#запись нового файла, опционально, для просмотра корретности предудыщих действий
file_new.to_excel('C:/Users/1/Desktop/xls2.xlsx', index=False)

for i in range(lines_number-1):

    if file.iloc[i][0] == file.iloc[i+1][0] and file.iloc[i][2] == file.iloc[i+1][2]:
        print('Equal')
    else:
        print('Not equal')
```

Вроде, разобрался, вот такой метод работает:

```
import pandas as pd

#загрузка исходного файла
xls0 = 'C:/Users/1/Desktop/xls1.xlsx'
file = pd.read_excel(xls0)

file_new = file.groupby(['Артикул', 'Размер'])['Артикул WB', 'Заказали, шт.', 'Заказали, руб.', 'Выкупили, шт.', 'Выкупили, руб.', 'Остаток, шт.'].sum().reset_index()

#запись нового файла
file_new.to_excel('C:/Users/1/Desktop/xls2.xlsx', index=False)
```

хотя и выдает предупреждение "FutureWarning: Indexing with multiple keys (implicitly converted to a tuple of keys) will be deprecated"

Comment: ну так вы в вопросе покажите, как вы используете библиотеку pandas. заодно пример данных должен быть в текстовом виде, а не скриншотом.

Comment: код который пока что написал - добавил, но не знаю как сюда добавить саму таблицу

Comment: Возможно стоит использовать функцию .groupby()? А не циклы

Comment: Если вы используете циклы с pandas, то 99% вы делаете что-то не так. Решение с groupby абсолютно верное, чтобы избежать предупреждения, возьмите колонки группировки в еще одни скобки: `file.groupby(['Артикул', 'Размер'])[['Артикул WB', 'Заказали, шт.', 'Заказали, руб.', 'Выкупили, шт.', 'Выкупили, руб.', 'Остаток, шт.']].sum().reset_index()`

Comment: спасибо, помогло, проблема решена!